# uploadify video encode with ffmpeg and encoding progress

Tags: php, ffmpeg, uploadify

want to know how to encode uploaded video files through the uploadify
I do tried a lot. I call the uploaded file and use the encode script using ffmpeg in uploadify.php file in the uploadify but its not doing nothing. Also I need to show he progress of encoding in the front-end interface

The ffmpeg script is working correctly in ssh putty client. But nothing happens inside uploadify.

Please help me in this regard
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Once uploadify is done with the file, you will need to have the uploaded file be executed with some FFMPEG parameters.  To return output from CLI:

```
    $file = file_get_contents("php://stdin", "r");
    echo $file;
```

Will return what the CLI command is doing, you would then simply scrape for data you would need to create a "progress" bar on a front end.

http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/
I would suggest using this.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-command/index.html